# TAP - Use internal EAP-method to reduce the code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've got a synchronous method that looks like this:

```
public void DownloadPackages()
    {
        long received = 0;
        double total = PackageConfigurations.Select(config => SizeHelper.GetRemoteFileSize(config.UpdatePackageUri))
            .Where(updatePackageSize => updatePackageSize != null)
            .Sum(updatePackageSize => updatePackageSize.Value);

        if (!Directory.Exists(_applicationUpdateDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_applicationUpdateDirectory);

        foreach (var updateConfiguration in PackageConfigurations)
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = null;
            try
            {
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(updateConfiguration.UpdatePackageUri);
                using (webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                    _packageFilePaths.Add(new UpdateVersion(updateConfiguration.LiteralVersion),
                        Path.Combine(_applicationUpdateDirectory,
                            $"{updateConfiguration.LiteralVersion}.zip"));
                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(_applicationUpdateDirectory,
                        $"{updateConfiguration.LiteralVersion}.zip")))
                    {
                        using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            if (input == null)
                                throw new Exception("The response stream couldn't be read.");

                            int size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            while (size > 0)
                            {
                                if (_downloadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                                {
                                    fileStream.Flush();
                                    fileStream.Close();
                                    throw new OperationCanceledException(_downloadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
                                }

                                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                received += size;
                                    OnUpdateDownloadProgressChanged(received,
                                        (long)total, (float)(received / total) * 100);
                                size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                webResponse?.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, I've implemented the EAP. This means that I've written a method that wraps this method in a task and raises events:

```
public void DownloadPackagesAsync()
    {
        _downloadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        _downloadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
               Task.Factory.StartNew(DownloadPackages).ContinueWith(DownloadTaskCompleted,
            _downloadCancellationTokenSource.Token,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

private void DownloadTaskCompleted(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
            return;

        var exception = task.Exception;
        if (exception != null)
            OnUpdateDownloadFailed(exception.InnerException ?? exception);
        else
            OnUpdateDownloadFinished(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

First question: Is it correct to update the progress in the synchronous method or is there an alternative way?

Second question: There is a private field that manages the `CancellationTokenSource` in my class and I am offering a method that looks like this:

```
public void CancelDownload()
    {
        _downloadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
```

When this method is being called, the download is being cancelled. But, is this also correct when I am using the TAP?

Now, the third question concerns the async method using TAP.
It should be `public async Task DownloadPackagesTaskAsync(IProgress<UpdateDownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> progress)`. Actually I would need to copy the whole code and adjust it, but this would bring me a lot of redundant lines, I think. I thought about using the EAP-method internally. The problem is that I don't have any return type and consecutively I can't use a `TaskCompletionSource` in order to use it. My orientation was the code in the .NET-Framework: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,d250a06fb9c3ac77,references

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Using `StartNew` to write fake asynchronous methods [is an anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). If your work is asynchronous, the API should be asynchronous. If you need to support a synchronous API for backcompat reasons, then use the boolean flag argument hack described [in my article on brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well, I've implemented the EAP

Why? Especially since you apparently intend to implement TAP anyway, why bother with EAP at all? For that matter, why is `DownloadPackages()` synchronous? The web APIs work very well asynchronously, using them that way would be more efficiently of your thread resources, and of course would naturally lend itself to a TAP-based API for your own code.

Personally, I would just change `DownloadPackages()` to be `async Task DownloadPackagesAsync()` (or include `IProgress<T>` parameter if you like as well), making the appropriate changes within the method to call the web and file APIs asynchronously with `await`, and leave it at that.

That said…

> Is it correct to update the progress in the synchronous method or is there an alternative way?

"Correct" according to what standard?

Certainly it will work as you have it. You left out the implementation of `OnUpdateDownloadProgressChanged()`, so it's not possible for us to know specifically what this does. But it's not uncommon for clients of EAP code to be required to handle cross-thread invocation themselves as needed, so I don't see anything wrong per se here.

Note, of course, that if you implemented the main method as `async`, this would have the effect of marshaling back to the correct context on the progress updates. Which is nicer. But not required.

> I am offering a method that looks like this …
>   When this method is being called, the download is being cancelled. But, is this also correct when I am using the TAP?

Again, "correct" according to what standard? My personal feeling is that it is. I wouldn't want to expose the `TaskCancellationSource` itself, so encapsulating the cancel operation in a public method seems right to me. But it's hard to say for sure without knowing by what criteria you want to judge the design.

> Now, the third question concerns the async method using TAP. It should be `public async Task DownloadPackagesTaskAsync(IProgress<UpdateDownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> progress)`. Actually I would need to copy the whole code and adjust it, but this would bring me a lot of redundant lines, I think. I thought about using the EAP-method internally. The problem is that I don't have any return type and consecutively I can't use a `TaskCompletionSource` in order to use it. … Is there any way to achieve this?

Again, if you simply implemented the original API as `async`, this would not even come up. That said, I don't understand your comments here. If you wanted to take the code you have now and present it as a TAP-style API, it seems to me you could simply do this:

```
public Task DownloadPackagesAsync()
{
    _downloadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    _downloadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(DownloadPackages).ContinueWith(DownloadTaskCompleted,
        _downloadCancellationTokenSource.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

The addition of `IProgress<T>` is trivial. If you really want to preserve both the EAP and TAP style APIs, you simply need to adapt one to the other, according to your preference. For example, if you want the underlying implementation to use EAP, and wrap that in TAP, you can subscribe to the appropriate event yourself and call `IProgress<T>.Report()` in your handler. Alternatively, if you want the underlying implementation to use TAP, you can in the EAP wrapper pass an `IProgress<T>` instance to the implementation, and raise the appropriate event in the callback for `IProgress<T>`.

I don't see what the lack of a return type has to do with anything. No one is forcing you to not have a return type, are they? Nor do I see a need to use `TaskCompletionSource` at all; you already have multiple options for returning a `Task` object that will be completed at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There should be the possibility to use EAP as some clients would like to keep .NET 4.0 without having to install any NuGet Packages (Microsoft Async etc.).
But I could think about it.

Well, I did not specify any standards, I just thought of the normal TAP implementation.
Your idea just gave me the solution, I think. I can just return the `Task` created by `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` and change the return type. From that point it should be easy to use this method internally inside the TAP-method.